# Are there any lethal melee weapons?

Tags: invisible-inc

I've found plenty of lethal ranged weapons, but does Invisible, Inc. have any lethal melee weapons?

Comment: You know, of all the questions I've seen here, this one made me pause for the longest as I wondered what in the heck was going on. Congrats.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR: Invisible Inc has one lethal melee weapon, but you can't acquire it in an unmodded version.

---

There is an item hidden in `itemdefs.lua`. But first have a look at at scripts.zip/sim/abilities/melee.lua (186-192) for the `melee` ability (you can unzip the `scripts.zip` in the game's directory to get a look at the game logic and other interesting stuff):

```
local lethal = false


if simquery.getEquippedMelee( userUnit ):getTraits().lethalMelee then
    grapple = false
    lethal = true
end
```

So `melee` is by default non-lethal, unless the equipped weapon is lethal. `itemdefs.lua` now contains the following item:

```
item_baton = util.extend(melee_template)
{
    name = STRINGS.ITEMS.BATON,
    desc = STRINGS.ITEMS.BATON_TOOLTIP,
    flavor = STRINGS.ITEMS.BATON_FLAVOR,
    icon = "itemrigs/FloorProp_AmmoClip.png",
    profile_icon = "gui/icons/item_icons/items_icon_small/icon-item_tazer_small.png",
    profile_icon_100 = "gui/icons/item_icons/icon-item_tazer.png",      
    --profile_icon = "gui/items/icon-tazer-ftm.png",
    requirements = {  },
    traits = { damage = 1, melee = true, lethalMelee = true},
    value = 500,
    floorWeight = 1,
},
```

All other items which extend `melee_template` don't set `lethalMelee` to true, so that one should be the only one. It's a monofilament baton, according to `strings.lua`:

> ### MONOFILAMENT BATON
>
> #### Melee strikes are lethal
>
> Though it looks like a simple club, in reality it's a short whip, thanks to advances in molecular construction. The filament is nearly invisible to the eye, and the results are often as hard to look at.

***But*** the `item_baton` doesn't come up in any other file. It doesn't get dropped by guards, nor will Monst3r ever sell it. So even though the game supports lethal melee weapons, you will never acquire one in the current version.

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent answer! That baton sounds more like a [variable sword](http://larryniven.wikia.com/wiki/Variable_sword) than a baton! I hope they plan to implement it at some point.

Comment: You could probably modify the game's files so that either a) the weapon is gifted to you, b) can be looted from b1)special facilities, b2) containers, b3) guards, or c) be sold by either Monst3r or the ingame facility shops. Although I would probably change the requirements for that item, so that on needs a maxxed attribute.

Comment: Can you suggest a good resource for learning how to do that? Or is it a simple as modifying the lua files and putting them back in the zip?

Comment: @SaintWacko: Haven't tried it yet, but I guess it should be as easy as that, unless the game checks the checksum or something similarly. I didn't test that since I haven't finished the story yet.

Comment: @SaintWacko: Here's an update: Klei uses [MOAI](http://getmoai.com/) for this game and simply mounts the `scripts.zip` as a virtual file system. You can copy your original scripts.zip, change some files, and afterwards change the path in `main.lua`. I also found the debug console, Ctrl+\`, where (according to state-debug.lua), one should be able to generate every ingame object, but I haven't tried that yet (also not sure how to redirect input to the debugger). All in all, I still think it should be easy. Furthermore, you can probably add different armor piercing versions of the baton.